# Mapbox GL geocoder autocomplete

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to to create multiple input autocomplete search fields that function same as the demo at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/  . However, I do not want the Search input box to be inside the Map box, I want to have the Search field outside of the map. I have not found a good example of how to create this using the mapbox gl examples and api docs.

I am looking for something similar to Google Autocomplete feature (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) but in Mapbox GL where I can just reference and id (ie, id="from_address") and Mapbox will attach the autocomplete behavior.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-outside-the-map/

```
<div id='geocoder' class='geocoder'></div>

var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
});

document.getElementById('geocoder').appendChild(geocoder.onAdd(map));
```

Answer (score -1):

I have similar situation where I need to place the address search box outside of mapbox map. After research a lot I am able to do that using this example of mapbox - https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/map-center-geocoding/

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it, rather than posing it as a question.

Comment: What do you mean by - "If you have another question, please ask it" ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted what you were saying as: I'm also having this problem, rather than an answer. However, if you were to create a working demo in something like jsFiddle rather than linking to a Mapbox page, it would be more useful to future visitors.